# Generating chapter title

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I am trying to prepare chapters in my thesis as par the following requirements

1. Chapter number (in Arabic) shall appear as right justified at the top of the page in Candara 27 pt in italic face, and title using first letter capitals. No vertical gap shall be left between Chapter number and Chapter title. A gap of 5 lines (of 11pt thickness) should be used between Chapter heading and first paragraph.
2. A chapter can be divided into Sections, Sub­sections, and Sub-subsections so as to present different concepts separately. Sections and sub­sections can be numbered using decimal, e.g., 2.2 for the second section in Chapter 2 and 2.3.4 for the fourth sub­section in the third Section of Chapter 2. The Sub-subsections shall be numbered as “(a)”, “(b)”, ... No further sub-sectioning shall be done beyond this third level. Chapters, Sections, and Sub­sections shall be included in the contents with page numbers flushed to the right; the inner subsections shall not be included in the contents.
3. Chapter number should be started from 1.

I have prepared a `main.tex` file where I am including all my chapters one by one. A part of my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top = 1.25cm, bottom = 1.25cm, left = 3.5cm, right = 1.25cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{palatino, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, bookmark}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
    \include{frontpage/frontpage}

\tableofcontents
\include{toc}

\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{1}

\mainmatter
    \include{chapter2/chapter2}

\backmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

Chapter 2 begins with:

```
\chapter{Review of Literature} 

\section{Preliminaries of Graph theory}

    A graph $G = (V(G), E(G))$ is a
```

I am facing the following problems.

1. It does not generate the chapter number above the title.
2. Chapter numbering starts with 0.

Can you help me to fix them accordingly?

Comment: That's normal: `\chapter*` (with a star) is for unnumbered chapters. For the first point, as I understand the specifications you mention, the chapter number should be on the left of the chapter title?

Comment: Removing '*' generates an error in the log: "Use of \@chapter doesn't match its definition".

Comment: Remove also the `flushright`  environment from  the chapter title. You should take a look at the `titlesec` package documentation: it is devoted to customising all section-like titles.

Comment: I am looking at the user manual of titlesec package. I got an output. "Chapter number" and "chapter name" are coming at the left of the page. I need "number" and "chapter name" at the right top.

Comment: Could you post the code you used?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: Is it okay now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a first draft. I had to replace `Candara` by another font, as there's no package to use it with `pdflatex` (however, it can be used with `fontspec` and  `xe/lualatex`):

```
\documentclass[twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[vmargin= 1.25cm, left = 3.5cm, right = 1.25cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlecaps}
\setcounter{secnumdepth} {3}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, bookmark}%
\usepackage{newpxtext, newpxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
%
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\fontfamily{verdana}\fontsize{27pt}{34pt}\selectfont\filleft}{\thechapter.}{0.5em}{#1}
\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\fontfamily{verdana}\fontsize{27pt}{34pt}\selectfont\filleft}{}{0em}{#1}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{12pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{36pt}

\titleformat{\section}{\fontfamily{verdana}\Large}{\thesection}{0.5em}{#1}
\titleformat{name=\section, numberless}{\fontfamily{verdana}\Large}{}{0em}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontfamily{verdana}\large}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{#1}
 \titleformat{name=\subsection, numberless}{\fontfamily{verdana}\large}{}{0em}{\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#1}#1}

 \titleformat{\subsubsection}{\fontfamily{verdana}\large}{\thesubsubsection}{0.5em}{#1}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{(\alph{subsubsection})}

\titlecontents{chapter} [0em] %
{\bigskip\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont \bfseries}
{\thecontentslabel\quad}%\thecontentslabel
{}% numberless
{\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip] %

\titlecontents{section} [1.667em] %
{\medskip\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}%\thecontentslabel
{\hspace*{2.12em}}%numberless
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]%

\titlecontents{subsection} [3.76em] %
{\medskip\fontfamily{verdana}\selectfont}
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}%\thecontentslabel
{\hspace*{3.12em}}%numberless
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}[\smallskip]%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Review of Literature}

\section{Preliminaries of Graph theory}

    A graph $G = (V(G), E(G))$ is a

\section*{An unnumbered section}

\subsection{Different Kinds of Graphs}

\subsection*{Other Kinds of Graphs}

\subsubsection{A test subsub}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Gutta: Note the `palatino` package is obsolete, you should replace it with `newpxtext, newpxmath`, based on the `palatino` clone `TeX Gyre Pagella`.  Also, do you want  the table of contents to be typed with `Candara`?

Comment: Yes, how to do it? Is it possible to do in pdflatex?

Comment: @Dutta: I've added a code for the table of contents (including unnumbered chapters,sections and subsections).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help will be really beneficial for me.